# Post from nextjs api "proxy' send me a 404

Tags: post, proxy, cors, next.js13

I'm facing an issue with a POST request in my Next.js application (using the App router).
From a component, I want to send form data to a remote server. To secure my API keys and avoid exposing them as NEXT_PUBLIC_, I've implemented a kind of proxy. I first send my data with a POST request to a Next.js API route (http://localhost:3000/api/amelia/postBooking), and then from this API, I make a POST request to my remote server.
The issue arises at this point. When I test the requests from the component, everything works fine. However, the same POST request from the API returns a 404 error. Everything is supposed to be set up correctly; I'm retrieving the data to be sent properly. I even hard-coded my API keys to ensure that the issue is not related to that.
I tried adding the new URL (api/amelia/postBooking) to the CORS policy on my remote server, but it doesn't seem to help.
Do you have any ideas about the problem?

Here the sent to the component :

```
 const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
// console.log(values)

const formattedDateTime = formatDateTimeForStore(`${daySelected} ${hourSelected}`);

const requestData = {
  formattedDateTime,
  values,
  duration: service.duration,
  employeeID: employeeID,
  serviceId: serviceId,
 };
  const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/amelia/postBooking`, {
    data : requestData
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}
```

Now the post from the API :

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
const body = await request.json();
try {

    const duration = body.data.duration;
    const formattedDateTime = body.data.formattedDateTime;
    const values = body.data.values;
    const employeeID = body.data.employeeID;
    const serviceId = body.data.serviceId;

    console.log(values)
    const postBookingUrl = `bookings`;

        const postBooking = await axios.post(`**********/${postBookingUrl}`, {
            "type": "appointment",
            "bookings": [
                {
                    "extras": [],
                    "customFields": {},
                    "deposit": true,
                    "locale": "fr_FR",
                    "utcOffset": null,
                    "persons": 1,
                    "customerId": null,
                    "customer": {
                        "id": null,
                        "firstName": values.prenom,
                        "lastName": values.nom,
                        "email": values.email,
                        "phone": values.telephone,
                        "countryPhoneIso": "",
                        "externalId": null
                    },
                    "duration": duration
                }
            ],
            "payment": {
                "gateway": "onSite",
                "currency": "EUR",
                "data": {}
            },
            "recaptcha": null,
            "locale": "fr_FR",
            "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
            "bookingStart": "2023-12-28 11:45",
            "notifyParticipants": 1,
            "locationId": "1",
            "providerId": "1",
            "serviceId": "1",
            "utcOffset": null,
            "recurring": [],
            "package": [],
            "couponCode": null,
            "runInstantPostBookingActions": false
        },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    // 'Amelia': process.env.AMELIA_API,
                    "Amelia": "*****",
                    'Accept': "*/*",
                },
            }
        );
 

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "ok" }, { status: 200 });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error }, { status: 500 });
}
```

}